# Remove multiple rows from contentprovider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I tried to remove two rows from my content provider with no success.
Here's the query;

```
int rowdelted = 
       con.getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, clausole, null);
```

where clausole is a string like "_ID = 100 AND _ID = 101 AND _ID = 102".

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row has 1 ID, and to attempt to remove a single row with id of 100, and 101, and 102, would not work.

You probably mean to be OR'ing the values.

```
String clausole = "_ID = 100 OR _ID = 101 OR _ID = 102";
```

Comment: Actually what I need is to delete all three rows. Have I to execute three delete?

Comment: No, you should only have to do one, and use the String I posted rather than the one you posted.  You are AND'ing where you should be OR'ing.

Comment: Then you should be using: String clausole = "_ID IN (100,101,102)"; it might also by IS IN but I haven't check the syntax and can't remember off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String clausole = "_ID IN (100, 101, 102)";
```

or use range

```
String clausole = "_ID => 100 AND _ID <= 102";
```